# How to use an ontology with RosPy to identify object around robot?

Tags: python, mapping, ros, ontology

I am a beginner at ROS. And I'm working on a project in which I have to use the ontology provided to me to identify/label the objects around the robot.
(Eg. If the camera pans over a cup, it identifies it as a cup and gets its co-ordinates.)

Can someone help me understand how I could begin with this?

I have tried to search on the Internet so far and saw some open source ROS services, but I'm still a bit confused on how that would work in my case.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.